# Отключить перемотку на маршрут Google maps

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Доброго времени суток.
Рисую маршрут с помощью Google Maps JavaScript API. Включаю отрисовку маршрута примерно таким кодом:

```
directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: finish,
    waypoints: waypoints,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
}, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        window.alert('Проблема: ' + status);
    }
});
```

При подобной отрисовке маршрута карта перематывается и приближается так, чтобы маршрут был целиком на экране. Как предотвратить эту перемотку?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DirectionsRendererOptions object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) `preserveViewport`

> Type:  boolean By default, the input map is centered and zoomed to the
>   bounding box of this set of directions. If this option is set to true,
>   the viewport is left unchanged, unless the map's center and zoom were
>   never set.

В общем, при создании `directionsDisplay` в опциях нужно указать

```
{preserveViewport: true}
```